# JS. Реализация авторизации

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

я хочу написать авторизацию для своего сайта на JS. После того, как я введу в форму логин и пароль я отправляю их на сервер. Если пользователь с таким логином и паролем есть в базе данных. То я генерирую токен и возвращаю его пользователю. При дальнейшей работе пользователя с сайтом после авторизации я буду использовать токен, передавая его при отправке любого запроса. Вопрос: как мне сохранить токен? Добавить его в куки? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Использовать JWT и пихать в заголовок запроса Authorization

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivDjWYcKDZI